# Knockout Binding problems

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using ASP.NET MVC with knockout to build a calendar with events that when a user clicks on the event, an Ajax request is sent with the event data to a c# function.
I am having a tough time getting the error div to show up if the user is not logged in prior to clicking the add href, as well as the add href to call the proper function.

The parameters in the AddEvent are being populated from the ASP.NET View

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Hudl/Content/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Hudl/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="/Hudl/Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/Hudl/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Hudl/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/Hudl/Scripts/Google/Google.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Concert</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div><img src="/Hudl/Content/Images/curtains_closing.jpg" width="100%" height="200em"></div>

        <div class="title">
            7 2014
            <span id="signinButton">
                <span class="g-signin"
                data-callback="signinCallback"
                data-clientid="1071645370589-acdsg7rjbsk7dn5lecfbk83k9uh8fnaa.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
                data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div data-bind="visible: displayError" id="error" title="Must Login">
            <p>You must login to Google+ before you can add a concert to your calendar.</p>
        </div>

        <table border="1">
            <tr><th>Sun</th>    <th>Mon</th>    <th>Tue</th>    <th>Wed</th>    <th>Thu</th>    <th>Fri</th>    <th>Sat</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
                <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
                <td><div class="date">1</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">2</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">3</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">4</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">5</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><div class="date">6</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">7</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">8</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">9</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">10</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">11</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">12</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><div class="date">13</div></td>

                <td><div class="date">14
                        <div>
                            <a href="javascript:AddEvent('4', 'Paul McCartney', 'Can You Believe It?', '07/14/2014', '18:30', '23:30:00')">18:30</a>
                            Paul McCartney
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td><div class="date">15</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">16</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">17</div></td>

                <td><div class="date">18
                        <div>
                        <a href="javascript:AddEvent('9', 'Midwest Cup Show Choir Invitational', 'High school show choirs battling for the championship!', '07/18/2014', '13:30', '22:00:00')">13:30</a>
                        Midwest Cup Show Choir Invitational
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td><div class="date">19
                        <div>
                        <a href="javascript:AddEvent('8', 'Marc-Andre Hamelin', 'Classical piano styles of the new era.', '07/19/2014', '20:00', '23:30:00')">20:00</a>
                        Marc-Andre Hamelin
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><div class="date">20</div></td>
            <td><div class="date">21</div></td>
            <td><div class="date">22
                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:AddEvent('3', 'Edison', 'Family friendly.', '07/22/2014', '17:00', '20:00:00')">17:00</a>
                        Edison
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:AddEvent('6', 'Tracy Byrd', 'Kick off your shoes come on in!', '07/22/2014', '18:00', '23:00:00')">18:00</a>
                        Tracy Byrd
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="date">23</div></td>
            <td><div class="date">24
                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:AddEvent('2', 'Imagine Dragon', 'Hipsters Paradise.', '07/24/2014', '18:45', '23:00:00')">18:45</a>
                        Imagine Dragon
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:AddEvent('7', 'Blue Man Group', 'Vegas in Nebraska.', '07/24/2014', '20:00', '23:30:00')">20:00</a>
                        Blue Man Group
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="date">25</div></td>
            <td><div class="date">26</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><div class="date">27</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">28</div></td>
                <td><div class="date">29</div></td>

                <td><div class="date">30
                        <div><a href="javascript:AddEvent('1', 'Powerman 5000', 'Heavy Metal Awesomeness!', '07/30/2014', '18:30', '23:30:00')">18:30</a>
                            Powerman 5000
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="date">31</div>
                </td>

                <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
                <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();
            function signinCallback(authResult) {
            this.authResult = authResult;
            if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
            document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            } else {
            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
            }
            };
        </script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
            $("#error").dialog();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my js

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.displayError = ko.observable(false);

    self.addEvent = function(id, artist, description, date, startTime, endTime) {
        if (!authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
            self.displayError = true;
            self.errorMessage = 'You are not logged-in to your google account.';
        } else {
            XMLHttpRequest.open("Get", "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList", true);
            //make google api call to get list of calendars based on authResult value in callback function

            //if api call to get calendars is successful, use authResult, concert, and calendarID to insert event into to make a new google api call to insert event

        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

right now i am receiving "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" everywhere that a javascript function is being called.

Comment: `self.displayError = ko.Observable(false);` should be lowercase `observable`.   Can you put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Joe no change with lowercase...im going to change my view to complete HTML to get the ASP.NET aspect out of the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and created a fiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/RKD9J/.

Key change was to use a knockout data binding handler for the click event to add a concert.

`<a href="javascript:AddEvent('1', 'Powerman 5000', 'Heavy Metal Awesomeness!', '07/30/2014', '18:30', '23:30:00')">18:30</a>Powerman 5000`

Changes to

`<a href="#" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { addEvent('1', 'Powerman 5000', 'Heavy Metal Awesomeness!', '07/30/2014', '18:30', '23:30:00') }" >18:30</a> Powerman 5000`

Following the instructions for passing arguments to functions found here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Your `javascript:AddEvent` statement is assuming that there is an `AddEvent` declared at the top (window) level, not on your view model.

Comment: when i load the page, the <div id="error"> is set to visible when it should be set to false. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/RKD9J/2/

Comment: If you hit F12 to bring up the dev tools console you'll see a couple of errors ($ not defined because we have no jQueery and a problem with the call back from google).  Because of these, the databinding isn't happening.  If you comment out the offending code, it seems ok ( http://jsfiddle.net/RKD9J/5/ )

Comment: Not quite, notice the self.displayError = true on line 24 of the JS. This doesnt make the div appear when clicking Powerman500's time

Comment: displayError is an observable - needs to be `self.displayError(true)` instead of `self.displayError = true` (http://jsfiddle.net/RKD9J/6/)

Comment: It seems to be having an issue on my `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());` line in Google.js